# how to deploy java application on heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, server

I want to Deploy my server side java application on a server. I choose to use Heroku. 
Currently, I am able to create server and client side application on java and run them from my laptop on different terminals and communicate between them. Now I want to do same over the internet and choose Heroku server but I don't understand how to deploy my application on its server. I tried to read their tutorial but I am not able to understand from it. Tutorials on youtube and other are very old.

Help me deploy my application to Heroku . I use Eclipse and know how to use git. Let me know if you need any other info.

Edit: As my first server application I would like to deploy a chat box. I will execute client side from my laptop and launch the server side (created by me) from Heroku.

Comment: Maybe you should [have a look at the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction), they explain the process very well themselves.

Comment: @px06 I cloned their example but I have no idea about any file except main.java . Like web.xml , pom.xml and others.

Comment: Could you update your post with information about what type a project you're trying to deploy? `pom.xml` is used my [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) which is a dependency management tool. `web.xml` is used to describe servlet mappings of a Java web application. So it really depends on what you're using on your project and what you're trying to deploy it as. Heroku is generally used to host web-applications but is not limited to them.